# How to find the speed of communication between client and server in Python?

Tags: python, network-programming, ping

I have a localhost where  I want to test the speed of communication between client and server. I want to ping `69.43.202.97` and find the connection speed in bytes/sec or kb/sec? I want to test the speed each 5 minutes and return it. How can I do that?

I used subprocess to ping the server:

```
subprocess.Popen(['ping', '69.43.202.97'])
```

It keeps returning the data. But I want to find the data transfer per second only in interval of 5 minutes.

Comment: Normal ping linux command with subprocess.

Comment: ping -c 1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx will just send one ping request

Comment: Yeah did that too. Also parsed time=514. It's unit is in milisecond right? How can I get the speed like? 1kb/sec or 1byte/sec?

Comment: The rate is packet size / time, but a standard ping is not sending much data so you don't really want to use that. You can set the size of of the packet with -s, but I would rather do this using ftp/scp with some test files of random data of various sizes.